# Expanderview in listbox, Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, expander

I am binding comments of user to expander view. The code looks

```
<ListBox..>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <toolkit:ExpanderView>
            ..
        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When we expand two or more items and then scroll till down/up of listbox, and then back to that expanded items, the expander view are overlapping with one another disturbing Ui.

Whether there is any solution for this?

Comment: The best solution would appear to be "don't do that": nesting ListBoxes (or things like ListBox such as ExpanderView) is almost always a bad idea performance wise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in November 2011 latest update toolkit.